# SQL Search multiple columns then update RichTextBoxes VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm running into an issue where I search a table and have the results fill RichTextBoxes.  Where I'm running into an issue is that I am using multiple readers for each RichTextBox.  While it works, I feel there is a better way to do this.

My table has multiple columns, one for store number (unique, non-duplicating), One for a main tech [Main 1] (This will be the same for multiple stores), one for a secondary tech [Main 2] (this will be the same for multiple stores) and so on.

I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to search [main 1] and return the stores to RichPrimaryTech(RichTextBox), search [main 2] and return the stores to RichSecondaryTech(RichTextBox), and so on using a single OleDbReader vs. multiple readers?

The other reason why I'm asking this, is I will be doing this again for another part of this form, and I'm trying to not duplicate a bunch of work or use multiple readers.

```
Private Sub ButtonLookUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonLookUp.Click
    If ComboTechSelect.SelectedItem = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing Selected")
    Else
        Dim setech As String = ComboTechSelect.SelectedItem
        Dim MainTechDataFile As String
        Dim MainTechConnString As String
        Dim MainTechConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim MR As OleDbDataReader
        Dim DX As OleDbDataReader
        Dim TX As OleDbDataReader

        Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        MainTechDataFile = "D:\\GateTechDBTest.accdb"
        MainTechConnString = provider & MainTechDataFile
        MainTechConnection.ConnectionString = MainTechConnString


        MainTechConnection.Open()

        Dim query As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * From Gtech WHERE [Gate Tech] = @tech", MainTechConnection)
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech", setech)


        MR = query.ExecuteReader
        While MR.Read()
            DTPLiability.Text = MR("Liability").ToString
            DTPWorkersComp.Text = MR("Workers Comp").ToString
            DTPAutoLiability.Text = MR("Auto Liability").ToString
            DTPExcessLiability.Text = MR("Excess Liability").ToString
            TextGateTechStreet.Text = MR("Address").ToString
            TextTechCity.Text = MR("City, State").ToString
            TextBoxTechZip.Text = MR("Zip").ToString
            TextTechPhone.Text = MR("Phone Number").ToString
            TextTechFax.Text = MR("Fax").ToString

        End While

        Dim stores As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * From Search WHERE [Main 1] = @tech1", MainTechConnection)
        stores.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech1", setech)

        DX = stores.ExecuteReader
        While DX.Read()
            RichPrimaryTech.AppendText(DX("Store").ToString + Environment.NewLine)
        End While


        Dim stores2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * From Search WHERE [Main 2] = @tech2", MainTechConnection)
        stores2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech2", setech)

        TX = stores2.ExecuteReader
        While TX.Read()
            RichSecondaryTech.AppendText(TX("Store").ToString + Environment.NewLine)
        End While

        MainTechConnection.Close()

        DTPAutoLiability.Enabled = True
        DTPExcessLiability.Enabled = True
        DTPLiability.Enabled = True
        DTPWorkersComp.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put your selects all in one go and return a dataset. Then you only need to make one call... You can use an adapter to fill the dataset... Also IMHO make a function to return that data, dont put it in the UI... then you can call it anywhere you need it.

Comment: That may not be doing what you think it is.  You are just running 3 different searches.  If the user is expecting the data *where Gate = @A AND main1 = @B AND main2 = @C* that is not what the code is doing.  The code shows 2 tables being queried not just multipole columns as in the title. So, you need to learn how to JOIN.